# How to make the size of my text fill more of its existing line-height?

Tags: html, css

I've setup a [mockup](https://jsfiddle.net/pgep1co9/1/) of a page where we display a users name, value, and units. I'm trying to get the value in the middle to fill the entire container. I've used `vh` units to set the height of both the font and parent, but I want to get the number closer to the row boundaries above and below.

If I add anymore height to the font-size, it just pushes the row below it down, causing a scroll bar to show up, and if I play with/remove the line-height it jumps the value above the upper row boundary. Responsively right now this works the way I'd like, except for the value not filling more of the container.

```css
.row.userprofile {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: initial;
}

.person-1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
.person-1 .person-name,
.person-1 .person-value,
.person-1 .person-units {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.person-1 .person-name,
.person-1 .person-units {
  font-size: 9vh;
  line-height: 15vh;
  min-height: 15vh;
}
.person-1 .person-value {
  font-size: 70vh;
  line-height: 1.0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row userprofile">
    <div class="small-5 columns person-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns person-name">Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns person-value">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 columns person-units">1 2 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I remove more of the space above and below the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's ultimately a completely reliable way to do this, fonts will render in several ways we don't have very much control over. But I think the closest you can get it to wrap the number in `<p>` tags and scale it. It's parent needs to then have it's overflow hidden to not create a scrollbar :

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xgd1eymv/)

```
.person-1 .person-value {
    font-size: 70vh;
    line-height: 70vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 70vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.person-1 .person-value p {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.38);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.38);
    transform: scale(1.38);
    margin: 0;
}
```

Adding a line height the same as the container height will compensate a bit for different rendering.
With Times New Roman as the font, a factor of 1.38 looks about the limit - mostly with IE.

It could also be done without scaling by the way (although I like it myself), hiding overflow on the parent works when giving the text element a larger size too :

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/d23wjppr/)

```
.person-1 .person-value {
    line-height: 70vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 70vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.person-1 .person-value p {
    font-size: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, that's perfect thanks.  Sorry for the late response it's the weekend so I'm only partially paying attention to my laptop.  Looks like when I responded to another answer I didn't notice yours, cheers.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for following up. Feeling not so left behind now, lol.